# TCL - Calling Specific Function if Scripts goes in infinite loop

Tags: tcl

Is there any mechanism in TCL by which i can check TCL Script for going in infinite loop?

For example, 
I have Test.tcl from which i want to check my a.tcl goes into infinite loop or not? If my a.tcl goes into infinite loop, is it possible to call certain function that "your a.tcl goes infinite loop."

Kind of timers function in c.

Hope that i am clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `interp limit` functions which allows something similar.

Detecting an infinite loop is kind of like the `halting problem` so, you can only set a timeout you wish to wait, but not really detect if there really is an infinite loop in the general case.

In some special cases, Tcl warns you if you try to create an infinite loop, especially when trying to start an event loop (via `vwait forever`) when there is no event source registered.

For `interp limit` see the documentation at:
http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/interp.htm#M22

It has an example for terminating an infinite loop in a subinterpreter after a certain amount of commands executed.

```
set i [interp create]
interp limit $i command -value 1000
interp eval $i {
    set x 0
    while {1} {
        puts "Counting up... [incr x]"
    }
}
```

You can also limit the time allowed for execution.

```
set i [interp create]
# set a limit to now + 1 seconds
interp limit $i time -seconds [expr {[clock seconds] + 1}]
interp eval $i {
    set x 0
    while {1} {
        puts "Counting up... [incr x]"
    }
}
```

Comment: The vwait infinite-loop detector is turned off in threaded mode IIRC — the code knows it just can't see inside what other threads are up to — and that's default in modern Tcl builds. Limits are the best built-in approach, though installing a signal handler via the async API might work too (unfortunately needs an extension like TclX or Expect; that feature's not exposed in the Tcl script API by default).

Comment: Hi @DonalFellows interp limit $i time -second 1 is not working properly. means i am expecting my loop to be break after 1 second. Is it true. or i need something

Comment: @Axit Soni: Read the documentation. -seconds 1 means you want the limit enforced at 1. January 1970 00:00:01. (its also spelled -seconds with an 's')